# Unable to bind a key in ledger-mode-map

Tags: keymap, ledger

Having written a function (say, `my-func`), I wanted to map it in `ledger-mode-map` to the keypress that I will call "Control dollar," that is, the dollar sign $, typed while the Ctrl key is held down.

The expression:

```
(define-key ledger-mode-map (kbd "C-$") 'my-func)
```

when executed does not indicate a failure, but a subsequent `C-h my-func` indicates no key binding.

Executing `C-h k C-$` produces the output "C-$ is undefined".

I need a way to express "Control dollar" so that Emacs can recognize it as a keypress, if that is even possible.  Here are a few of the alternatives I have tried to `(kbd "C-$")`:

| Expression | Result when evaluated |
| --- | --- |
| [?\C-4] | 67108916 |
| [?\C-\$] | 67108900 |
| (kbd "C-\$") | 67108900 |
| [C-S-4] | [C-S-4] |
| (kbd "[67108900]") | "[67108916]" |
| [$] | [$] |
| [\$] | [$] |
| (kbd "C-[$]") | C- must prefix a single character, not [$] |
| (kbd "C-$") | 67108900 |
| [(control $)] | [(control $)] |
| [(control \$)] | [(control $)] |

@amitp: It does work if I use `global-map` instead of `ledger-mode-map`. It does not work if I use, say, `C-!` instead of `C-$` with `ledger-mode-map`.

Comment: Hm, interesting. To narrow it down, let's try to figure out if it's the `C-$` part or the mode map part. Does it work if you use `global-map` instead of `ledger-mode-map`? Does it work if you use a different keybinding instead of `C-$`?

Comment: It does work if I use `global-map` instead of `ledger-mode-map`.  It does not work if I use, say, `C-!` instead of `C-$` with `ledger-mode-map`

Comment: Since the problem is with `ledger-mode-map`, which is not bundled with Emacs, can you please provide a way to reproduce the problem from `emacs -q`? E.g. how you installed ledger-mode, which version exactly. Do you have the same problem if you run `emacs -q` and do whatever minimum steps are needed to enable Ledger mode?

Comment: This is all you ever need as a key description: `(kbd "C-$")`. `kbd` accepts as input what Emacs shows you as help when you use `C-h k`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': I set up a minimal ledger-mode environment, and in that the key assignment did work correctly.

Comment: It looks like my use of the `:bind*` section of `use-package` may be the culprit.  I had a couple of assignments to `ledger-mode-map` there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MWE:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org"   . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/"    ) t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"   ) t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)

(defun my-func ()
  "Say `HEY'."
  (interactive)
  (message "HEY"))

(use-package ledger-mode
  :ensure         t
  :bind           (:map ledger-mode-map
                        ("<C-f13>"   . my-func)))

(define-key ledger-mode-map (kbd "C-$") 'my-func)
```

If we evaluate the above expression, then edit a buffer in ledger-mode, and then press either `C-$`or `C-f13`, "HEY" shows up in the minibuffer.

But if instead of using `define-key` to do the mapping for `C-$`, we add it to the `:bind` section of `use-package` thus:

```
(use-package ledger-mode
  :ensure         t
  :bind           (:map ledger-mode-map
                        ("<C-f13>"   . my-func)
                        ((kbd "C-$") . my-func)))
```

and then evaluate the expression, the `*Warnings*` buffer displays this:
`Error (use-package): Failed to parse package ledger-mode: use-package: ledger-mode wants arguments acceptable to the 'bind-keys' macro, or a list of such values`

The trick is to change that last line from

```
                        ((kbd "C-$") . my-func)))
```

to

```
                        ("C-$"       . my-func)))
```

Then once again either `C-$` or `C-f13` display "HEY" in the minibuffer.